# Is there an exposé like window overview feature in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, window-manager, productivity, expo-mode

Using Ubuntu with unity and compiz it was possible for me to create a hot corner which triggered all (in-)active windows to be shown in an overview.

Is it possible to create something similar in xubuntu?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[skippy-xd](https://code.google.com/p/skippy-xd/) is the closest thing I can see.

- Code and bug tracker: https://github.com/richardgv/skippy-xd/
- PPA: https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/skippy-xd-daily/

I'd check the bug tracker because this doesn't come without issues.

You can install the PPA with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:landronimirc/skippy-xd-daily
sudo apt-get install skippy-xd
mkdir -p ~/.config/skippy-xd
wget -qO ~/.config/skippy-xd/skippy-xd.rc https://raw.github.com/richardgv/skippy-xd/master/skippy-xd.sample.rc
```

Then you just need to run `skippy-xd` to see the windows laid out. You can [set a keyboard binding for that](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings) to make things easier.

Comment: i bound this with `fusuma` on the four fingers up gesture and it works like a charm. highly recommend  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034624/touchpad-gestures-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts