# How to add 'show all windows' functionality in xubuntu?

Tags: xfce, mint

I would like a hot corner functionality similar to that of Linux mint 17. Is there any way I can achieve that on Xubuntu?

Comment: something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mr77FLgy0YI  except it just show the current workspace and its windows minimized

Comment: Wait, it canbe done, if this http://askubuntu.com/q/434137/72216 still works, I  an make it work for you with the hot corner. Could you try and post back? (Baking oliebollen at the moment :) )

Comment: Yeah I bound the skippy-xd in the hotcorner plugin, thanks for the link, donno what oliebollen is though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First install 'xfdashboard'

Install Xubuntu Extras.  [SOURCE](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/ubuntu/extras)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/extras

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install xfdashboard
```

To set up hot corners:

**Option 1**

1. Open '**xfdashboard settings**' in the program menu
2. Select '**Plugins**' tab
3. Select '**Hot Corner**'and tick option
4. Select '**Preferences**'
5. CLose
6. Reboot system

**Option 2**
[SOURCE](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/set-up-hot-corners-edge-flipping-in.html)

```
sudo apt-get install brightside
```

Once installed, open terminal and enter:

```
brightside-properties
```

In properties:

1. Select Corner, tick box
2. In drop down select 'custom action'
3. Enter '**xfdashboard**' in *'On entering region'*
4. Adjust delay
5. Close properties

Once configured add '**brightside**' to startup applications list. Instruction [HERE](https://xubuntugeek.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/add-application-to-xfcexubuntu-session.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can try xfce4-hotcorner-plugin:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/extras
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfce4-hotcorner-plugin
```

Comment: I already had this plugin, that didn't resolve showing the windows all minimized.