# Fusuma not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, xdotool, libinput

I have **Ubuntu 18.04** on **Dell Vostro 15 - 3546**.

```
uname -api

Linux vaishnavi-laptop 4.15.0-117-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 20:02:41 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044184/1013762) to install `fusuma`. Then when I run `sudo fusuma`:

```
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:33.978824 #15466]  INFO -- : reload config: /home/vaishnavi/.config/fusuma/config.yml
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.051674 #15466]  INFO -- : ---------------------------------------------
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.051794 #15466]  INFO -- : Fusuma: 1.11.1
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.061094 #15466]  INFO -- : libinput: 1.10.4
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.143106 #15466]  INFO -- : OS: Linux 4.15.0-117-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 20:02:41 UTC 2020
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.145421 #15466]  INFO -- : Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS \n \l
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.147262 #15466]  INFO -- : Desktop session:
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.147340 #15466]  INFO -- : ---------------------------------------------
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.147393 #15466]  INFO -- : Enabled Plugins: 
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.147612 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Buffers::GestureBuffer
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.147659 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Detectors::PinchDetector
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.147692 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Detectors::RotateDetector
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.147729 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Detectors::SwipeDetector
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.147764 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Events::Records::GestureRecord
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.147804 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Events::Records::IndexRecord
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.147948 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Events::Records::TextRecord
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.147979 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Executors::CommandExecutor
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.148008 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Filters::LibinputDeviceFilter
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.148039 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Filters::LibinputTimeoutFilter
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.148081 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Inputs::LibinputCommandInput
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.148119 #15466]  INFO -- :   Fusuma::Plugin::Parsers::LibinputGestureParser
I, [2020-09-15T09:45:34.148177 #15466]  INFO -- : ---------------------------------------------
```

I didn't miss any step nor did I close the terminal, but still touchpad gestures don't work!
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Contents of `/home/vaishnavi/.config/fusuma/config.yml`:

```
swipe:
  3:
    left:
      command: "xdotool key Alt+Right" # History forward 
    right:
      command: "xdotool key Alt+Left" # History back
    up:
      command: "xdotool key Super" # Activity
    down:
      command: "xdotool key Super" # Activity
  4:
    left:
      command: "xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+Down" # Switch to next workspace
    right:
      command: "xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+Up" # Switch to previous workspace
    up:
      command: "xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+Down" # Switch to next workspace
    down:
      command: "xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+Up" # Switch to previous workspace
pinch:
  in:
    command: "xdotool keydown Ctrl click 4 keyup Ctrl" # Zoom in
  out:
    command: "xdotool keydown Ctrl click 5 keyup Ctrl" # Zoom out
```

Comment: Could you test what I proposed? It is as simple as running without sudo.

Comment: Would you mind posting the contents of your /home/vaishnavi/.config/fusuma/config.yml?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I added the contents of `config.yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the output you have attached here, I think the fusuma is configured successfully actually. Here I'm attaching my output  [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6POYw.png).
and after this i tried to use my gestures and it works completely fine. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp5Te.png) is the screenshot.

So, in your case maybe you haven't followed the tutorial carefully or it may be that your `dependencies` are not completely installed or you haven't configured your `config.yml` file.

I suggest you to again go through that complete process or check your `config.yml` file first, Moreover you can just install all the dependencies like

```
$ sudo apt-get install libinput-tools  
$ sudo apt-get install xdotool 
$ sudo apt install ruby  
$ sudo gem install fusuma
```

And now one more suggetion you can try is that first you find your default path of fusuma and run that from there like.

```
$ whereis fusuma
```

let's say the output will be something like `/usr/local/bin/fusuma` (this is in my case)

and run this like

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/fusuma
```

also you can try to run this as without using `sudo` privileges, maybe it is causing some issue, but I'm not completely sure about this.

Hope this may help.

Comment: After a reinstallation, this worked, Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome...!!

Answer (score 1):

As per [this post](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma/issues/110#issuecomment-450077059), when you run `fusuma` with `sudo` the config file is not *properly* (whatever that means) read.
You have to run it as your regular user.
I am not sure in which cases using `sudo` would work or not. As per the voting of [the answer you linked](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044184/226614), it does work in many cases.

Note that in [a post by the developer of fusuma](https://dev.to/iberianpig/how-to-install-and-customize-fusuma-73l), it is started without `sudo`.
It is worth reading that post, since it mentions a couple of points that may be crucial:

1. You "need to log out and log in (or restart) from X".
2. `fusuma -d` keeps it running in the background when the terminal is closed.

Consistently, in [the Github readme page](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma/blob/master/README.md), which contains the installation instructions linked in [the answer you linked](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044184/226614), `fusuma` is also run without `sudo`. I wouldn't know why the answerer Rachit Kinger uses `sudo`.

You can take advantage of `libinput debug-gui` in this or other occasion, as also mentioned in that same thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Please paste output of `$ libinput debug-events` with 3 finger swipe.

If you find lines related to swipe in logs, fusuma can detect gestures.